# SQL Loader issue with loading

Tags: sql, oracle, loader

I'm trying to load data to the DB with SQL*Loader. Here is my loading scipt:

```
load data
 infile 'c:\MyFile.csv'
 append
 into table MyTable
 fields terminated by ',' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS 
(
 A number,
 B number,
 c number,
 .
 .
 .
 N char(4000),
 O number,
 P number
)
```

Some of the values of N column including `,`. For example: `AA,A`

Here is a row for eample:

```
123,111,555,541,546,AA,A,987,789
```

Due to this issue, i'm getting some errors while loaing the file into the DB.
How can i solve this issue?

Comment: Are the columns with the delimiter in them quoted, like they would be in a CSV file?

Comment: Yes, thats's how they appearing in the CSV file. Therfor they are detected as a seperated columns while it's supposed to be one column.

Comment: Whoever is providing the CSV file has to enclose any values with commas in double quotes; this isn't something you can reasonably fix at load time. (If there's only one char field then it's feasible you could do it via a staging or external table, but it still isn't reasonable you should have to).

Comment: OK, Thanks. I thought it's a common problem with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

replace your csv file delimiter with | sign or enclosed data with ", so your csv file data will be

```
"123"|"111"|"555"|"541"|"546"|"AA,A"|"987"|"789"
```

and use 
 `OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` in SQL Loader

e.g

```
load data
 infile 'c:\MyFile.csv'
 append
 into table MyTable
 fields terminated by '|'
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
TRAILING NULLCOLS 
(
 A number,
 B number,
 c number,
 .
 .
 .
 N char(4000),
 O number,
 P number
)
```

this will work.